# Video settings for Android phones

Tags: android, video, mpeg-4

We've been given a video ad for display on Android phones.  Unfortunately when we give it to one of the ad networks they send us the error back :

```
Error Message:
03-28 19:16:07.950: E/MPEG4Extractor(1695): Video is malformed
03-28 19:16:07.950: E/OMXCodec(1695): [OMX.SEC.avc.dec] err = -1007
03-28 19:16:07.985: E/OMXCodec(1695): [OMX.SEC.aac.dec] err = -1011
03-28 19:16:08.560: V/AwesomePlayer(1695): MEDIA_ERROR -1007
03-28 19:16:08.560: V/AwesomePlayer(1695): notifyListener_l() msg (100-MEDIA_ERROR), ext1 (1), ext2 (-1007)
03-28 19:16:08.560: V/MediaPlayerService(1695): [117] notify (0xa61d8, 100, 1, -1007)
03-28 19:16:08.560: V/AudioSink(1695): stop
03-28 19:16:08.560: V/MediaPlayer(19343): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1007
03-28 19:16:08.560: E/MediaPlayer(19343): error (1, -1007)
```

I can play the video on Mac/Windows through VLC with no problem. Can anyone help decipher the error message and let me know what it doesn't like?

Comment: Can you show us the http url string you're passing to the `MediaPlayer`, as well as some code ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Android tries to read your video but fails, because of some container parsing/decoding issues.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) is the complete list of media formats that Android supports for each version.

You might want to reencode/recopy your video file in one of the supported formats/codecs. I personnaly use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) which might be able to transcode your video to a fair amount of outputs. Also, he comes with some handy presets for Android phones.